# A bluetooth receiver that stays on and doesn't make sound when connecting, etc?

Tags: bluetooth

**Background**: I run public events for which I use an audio mixer to plug in a microphone and a music player. Sometimes the setup is such that I cannot get to the mixer physically during the event, but I do need access to the player. I can't use a cable as all the line inputs in the mixer are unbalanced and a long cable introduces noticeable noise. I've kind of solved the problem by getting a Bluetooth receiver that plugs into the mixer and then the player connects to it. However, the player goes to sleep after 30s of not playing anything at which point it disconnects from the Bluetooth receiver. The Bluetooth receiver then turns itself off and plays a voice prompt over the speakers.

So **I'm looking for a Bluetooth receiver that**

1. always stays on even when there's no device connected (so that I can later reconnect to it without physically getting to it), and
2. does not make any sound (such as beep or speech) when a device is connecting or at any other time

Can anyone confidently recommend a brand and model that meets these two requirements?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [classic XY problem](https://xyproblem.info), so it was very nice to read what your real problem was!

> I can't use a cable as all the line inputs in the mixer are unbalanced and a long cable introduces noticeable noise.

Get a pair of audio baluns then. Or one balun and a better mixer :)

Balun is short for "balanced-unbalanced". These devices convert between balanced and unbalanced lines. You want an audio balun, since there also are RF baluns, and those are not what you need at all.

> I've kind of solved the problem by getting a Bluetooth receiver

Sorry but that problem only appears solved because you haven't run into RF interference issues yet, firmware bugs, etc. And run into them you will for sure. Audio-over-Bluetooth and PA systems don't go together. Bluetooth in event production does the job for interfacing wireless controllers around the production desk - say a wireless mouse, a wireless pencil for a tablet, etc. Not much else, nor should it - it wasn't designed for that.

> I'm looking for a Bluetooth receiver [...]

You absolutely are not looking for a Bluetooth receiver, I can assure you of that. Forget about Bluetooth for event production. It will only seem "affordable" if you don't count wasted time, aggravation, and the potential of customers not choosing your services the next time.

If you need wireless audio, use a professional solution - there are very, very many of those. They don't do anything silly like Bluetooth receivers do, and they are resilient to interference and so on. Make sure to buy brand name products - stuff sold by major AV distributors in the US in Europe, not random stuff from AliExpress or Amazon.

I highly suggest going to look into professional audio forums to see what the recommendations are. A particular solution will depend highly on what the distances are, the environment (a venue with 50k people vs  50 people are very different beasts in terms of RF environment!), the line of sight or lack thereof between the transmitter and receiver antennas, whether it's a permanent installation or a temporary gig-time-only, etc.

Comment: I should have clarified that are events are *very* small and our budget is *very* limited. Hence a simple bluetooth receiver is what I definitely need, not a professional equipment for 50k people that costs hundres of dollars. The current bluetooth receiver I got for $30 works prefectly reliably except it has these two downsides I described. I am well aware of the solution you are proposing and it's outside our range.